# ClassNotFoundException in depdendent project

Tags: java, maven

I have a utils project that has dependencies like

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.56</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And then my other project depends on utils:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycomp.proj</groupId>
        <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
        <version>${utils.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

This works fine without issue.  Then I added this package to utils:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jopt-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>jopt-simple</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

I `mvn clean install` utils first, then my main project and both build without errors.  But for some reason when I try to run the main project, when it reaches the class that uses jopt-simple, it crashes with

```
   ClassNotFoundException: joptsimple.OptionException
```

Any idea why I can run my main project fine without jopt-simple in the utils package but once I add it as a dependency it fails?  I've manually deleted the utils package in my m2 repo as well and rebuilt it to see if that fixed it but it did not.

Comment: If you were able to build without the dependency, that probably means the class was already present in the class path. Introducing the library, might have cause multiple implementations of the same class or override of the same. Could you share the relevant `mvn dependency:tree` of your project where you are using utils.

Comment: The dependency added below will override dependency above . if you are using eclipse than you can check the Effective pom . or in resloved dependency check which one is actually included . make sure the jar is not already in any build path of your project

Answer (score -1):

You can try following-  you can declare a dependency with system scope, which tells Maven that a particular JAR is assumed to be in the classpath

So maven won't be touching this dependency and you can put the jar in your classpath manually.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jopt-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>jopt-simple</artifactId>
    <version>4.9</version>
     <scope>system</scope>
</dependency>
```

Another option - If you want to manage this jar file yourself, you can manually add in classpath or local repo and then  try running maven in offline mode .

```
mvn -o install
```

Comment: *running maven in offline mode* how would that help?

Comment: If user has added the jar manually in local repo/classpath, then it wont download from remote repo. So external dependency will be gone. However if you want to download a external dependency then you can't run in offline mode.

Comment: *user has added the jar manually in local repo/classpath* doesn't seem to be the case though to me.

Comment: User can also go for this option, if he wants to manage it manually. I updated it in answer.

Comment: You're answering a slightly different question than OP is asking, and you're offering plain bad advice. I feel that not only your submission does not help the problem at hand, but if OP were to follow your advice, it would be worse for him (i.e. you're adding to the confusion).